# 2D rendering with VBO in lwjgl won't draw

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, vbo, lwjgl

I'm working on a 2D game in LWJGL. I have successfully rendered QUADS with textures using glBegin but moving to VBOs turned out to be a big undertaking. At the moment I can switch between the vbo and non-vbo rendering with a boolean, both using the same vertex- and texture coordinates. The VBO-implementation won't draw anything onto the screen. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my initialization:

```
public void init() {
    VBOID = VBOHandler.createVBOID();
    TBOID = VBOHandler.createVBOID();
    float[] vdata = {0, 0, 
                    width, 0,
                    width, height,
                    0, height};
    float[] tdata = {sx, sy, 
                     ex, sy, 
                     ex, ey, 
                     sx, ey};

    //Texture coordinates: (0,0)(1,0)(1,1) and (0,1)

    FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
    fb.put(vdata);
    VBOHandler.bufferData(VBOID, fb);
    fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(8);
    fb.put(tdata);
    VBOHandler.bufferData(TBOID, fb);
}
```

And here is my rendering code:

```
private void render() {
    texture.bind();
    if(vbo) {
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        VBOHandler.bindBuffer(VBOID);
        GL11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        VBOHandler.bindBuffer(TBOID);
        GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

        VBOHandler.bindElementBuffer(VBOHandler.getDefaultIBOID());
    // I figured why not use a standard IBO for all my sprite drawing
    // The default IBO ID is initialized earlier in the program, not shown in this code
        GL12.glDrawRangeElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 3, 4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    } else {
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(sx, sy);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(ex, sy);
        GL11.glVertex2f(width,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(ex, ey);
        GL11.glVertex2f(width, height);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(sx, ey);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0, height);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }

}
```

And the VBOHandler class, for those interested

```
public class VBOHandler {

    private static int IBOID;

public static void initDefaultIBO() {
    IBOID = createVBOID();
    short[] indexdata = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    ShortBuffer shortBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(4);
    shortBuffer.put(indexdata);
    VBOHandler.bufferElementData(IBOID, shortBuffer);
}

public static int getDefaultIBOID() {
    return IBOID;
}

public static int createVBOID() {
    if(GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        return ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();
    }
    return 0;
}

public static void bufferData(int id, FloatBuffer buffer) {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, id);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, buffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    }
}

public static void bufferElementData(int id, ShortBuffer buffer) {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, id);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, buffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    }
}

public static void bindBuffer(int id) {
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, id);
}

public static void bindElementBuffer(int id) {
    ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, id);
}
 }
```

The above render-function lies within my Sprite class. It is called by my GameView every frame as so:

```
public void renderGame() {
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    sprite.render();
}
```

The GameView is initialized with the following code:

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1024, 768));
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  
GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);         
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND); // enable alpha blending
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(x - width/2, x + width/2, y + height / 2, y - height / 2, -1, 1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: Quite unrelated comment: You could actually just drop your default IBO and just use glDrawArrays, as your IBO doesn't do more than just walking through your array in sequence.

Comment: Have you checked if buffer objects are supported and your buffer IDs have valid values (!=0)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. All my buffers have valid IDs (1,2 and 3 to be precise) and GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object returns true.

Comment: I cannot find anything. Perhaps your problem lies a bit deeper. Could you post some more code (maybe a minimal working example)?

Comment: I added some blocks of code. See if you can make anything sensible out of it

Comment: I hope you turned off back face culling, as your `glOrtho` causes all triangles to flip their orientation and show you their back faces. But I think in this case it should work, as otherwise your `glBegin/glEnd` wouldn't have worked either.

Comment: It wasn't disabled, but disabling it didn't do any difference.

Comment: Changing the rendering line to GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4) crashes the JRE. Any idea where to go from here Christian?

Comment: Solved this by adding fb.flip() before buffering the data.

Answer (score 0):

You did not call 'flip' on the FloatBuffers before passing them to OpenGL. You *need* to call 'flip()' on FloatBuffers before you pass them to OpenGL, or it will not be able to read them. It is worth noting that you cannot read the FloatBuffers after you call 'flip()' yourself.